# Como fazer upload de arquivo .txt e salvar em um diretorio utilizando c# .net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, upload

Gostaria de fazer upload de arquivos textos onde seleciono N arquivos .txt e salvo em um diretório que especifiquei na aplicação; fiz um exemplo que estava na internet mas não consegui obter os arquivos na minha action.

**Action:**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Upload upload)
    {
        foreach (var file in upload.Files) {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Arquivo"), filename);
                file.SaveAs(path);

        }

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**Modelo**

```
    public class Upload
{
    public IEnumerable <HttpPostedFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
      <h2>Upload de arquivo</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 { 

@Html.Label("File")
<input type="file" name="Files" id="Files" accept=".txt" multiple />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />



 }
```

Comment: Recomendo utilizar este plugin, ele é muito bom https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 1):

Você está utilizando uma classe que contém uma enumerador de `HttpPostedFile`.

---

O correto seria você receber os arquivos via `HttpPostedFileBase`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase Files)
{
    // Verifica se o usuário selecionou algum arquivo
    if (Files != null && Files.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // Extrai apenas o nome do arquivo
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(Files.FileName);
        // Armazena o arquivo dentro da pasta ~/Arquivo
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Arquivo"), fileName);
        Files.SaveAs(path);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu faço a geração de arquivos TXT desta forma:

```
    public FileResult DownloadFile(FileInfo file)
    {
        var extension = file.Extension;
        //Este é o content type utilizado para arquivos TXT  
        var contentType = "text/plain";
        //Em file.FullName está o caminho completo e nome do seu arquivo
        var stream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open);
        //Utilizando o FileMode.Open o arquivo será automaticamente gravado na pasta e baixado
        return File(stream, contentType, file.Name);
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Eu acho que no caso de vc fazer o upload de mais de um arquivo por vez vc precisa usar o PostedFiles fazendo um FOR. Tenta esse código.

```
   string nome = "";
   string caminho = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");

   for (int i = 0; i < FileUpload1.PostedFiles.Count; i++)
       {
        nome = nome + FileUpload1.PostedFiles[i].FileName + " - ";
        FileUpload1.PostedFiles[i].SaveAs(caminho + 
        FileUpload1.PostedFiles[i].FileName);
       }
       Alert("Arquivo(s): " + nome + ", enviado(s) com sucesso!");
       }
```

Boa sorte!